# Apache Solr filter like EdgeNGramFilterFactory that only consider complete words?

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm looking for a solr filter that can convert an input like

```
"This is a sentence"
```

in following tokens

```
"This", "This is", "This is a", "This is a sentence"
```

Is there such a filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lucene provides a filter, however it would generate Shingles

[solr.ShingleFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ShingleFilterFactory)
This will generate Shingles e.g. "This is a sentence" -> This is, is a, a sentence

else, you need to Extend or Implement your own.

Comment: Thanks. I hoped there is somewhere a secret filter that does the job ;) ShingleFilterFactory is not exactly what I need, so I have to write it on my own.